# NSFetchedResultsController not updating when saving to core data

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Any ideas on the following? Help greatly appreciated:

I have setup an `NSFetchedResultsController` as follows:

```
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {

    if self._fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return self._fetchedResultsController!
    }
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Messages", inManagedObjectContext: self.mOC)

    let messageRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    messageRequest.entity = entity
    let messagePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "messageFrom = %@ OR messageTo = %@", profileID, profileID)
    messageRequest.predicate = messagePredicate
    messageRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "messageDate", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
    messageRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: messageRequest, managedObjectContext: self.mOC, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionTitle", cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    self._fetchedResultsController = frc
    return self._fetchedResultsController!

}
```

It's linked by a to-many relationship with a Chats Entity. Chats >> Messages. One chatter (defined by CurrentChatter) has many messages.

When I load the tableview ... the messages show perfectly using the following in my `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let fetchError as NSError {
    print("I have been unable to fetch things .. : \(fetchError)")
}
```

When I save a message using the following boilerplate code, nothing seems to be happening with the `NSFetchedResultsController`. The tableView isn't updating for some reason and I can't seem to work out why. I have the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` in place and defined.

```
if let newMessage = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Messages", inManagedObjectContext: mOC) as? Messages {
    newMessage.messageDate = NSDate()
    newMessage.messageFrom = myMainUser.mainUserIDfromServer
    newMessage.messageMustBeSent = false
    newMessage.messageReceivedAtServer = true
    newMessage.messageCode = 0
    newMessage.messageType = 100
    newMessage.messageText = "Here is a message I am sending to you!"
    newMessage.messageTo = Int(profileID)!
    newMessage.messageNewMessage = false

    currentChatter.mutableSetValueForKey("messages").addObject(newMessage)          

    do {
        try mOC.save()
    } catch let saveError as NSError {
        print("I have not been able to save the message ...: \(saveError)")
    }
}
```

I'm calling mOC.save. I've checked that it's saved and that it's saving to the same `ManagedObjectContext`. When I manually refresh the tableview, the new message shows.

To test this is working I have a simple print statement as follows:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    print("I will make changes?")

}
```

Needless to say, this isn't getting called.

Is this because the new message is being added as part of my CurrentChatter. Or should it update each time there is a change to the Messages Entity? Or have I missed something entirely? 3 hours on this and I'm no closer to understanding why it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I've added code to sort the table by Date (added for reference):

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Messages: NSManagedObject {

    func sectionTitle() -> String {

        let myDate = NSDateFormatter()
        myDate.dateFormat = "d MMM YYYY"
        return myDate.stringFromDate(self.messageDate)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have typical use FRC delegate method code in your controller?

Comment: @Darren, did you found a solution???

Comment: @DmitriyGreh Sadly not. It remains the most frustrating thing. I gave up, to be honest, as no one here seemed to be able to help me. Please let me know if you have any luck.

Answer (score 2):

You set the delegate, but did you implement `controller didChangeObject` etc.? You need something like this:

```
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        case .Update
            // update cell at indexPath
        case .Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response! I have updated the question as I missed a func() declaration. I have a boilerplate print statement to check if the 'controllerWillChangeContent' was called. And it isn't being called.

Comment: Did you try setting the `sectionNameKeyPath` to nil?

Comment: Yes. No difference. Same behaviour. Nothing appears when I add a "message" until I reload the tableview manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the problem was that I had set the NSFRC delegate on the type variable before instantiating it with a result from `NSFetchedResultsController()` call. So the delegate was not being set and none of the delegate methods would work.

Silly mistake, I know, but took me a while to find it.

In your case, if you are getting back something for `type` in `didChangeObject` then your delegate is working fine.

You said you were getting the wrong values for `type`. Print the raw value of the `type` enum to see what they are. Here is a link to Apple's doc on them:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSFetchedResultsChangeType

Their order in the `switch` statement shouldn't matter as long as it is extensive (include them all).

Also, make sure that you are not expecting one type and receiving another. For example:

If adding a new entry, you would expect a `.Insert` correct? But if you are sorting by `name` in the NSFRC descriptor, you will receive a `.Move` instead because the new addition could cause a rearrangement of rows.

This also happened to me and took me a while to find.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the update statement BEFORE the .Insert in the didChangeObject (so put it on the first place), does that help? I had the same behavior and this fixed it for me.. At least, on my device. I now hear beta testers experiencing the same issue.. :(

Comment: No. Nothing has made any difference. When I look at the `type` value it's not showing the right action. So, when I 'update' a record, the `type` result is coming back as `delete` in the `didChangeObject` function. This really is annoying as, having used the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` I'm now having to use it by reloading the tableView manually each time I make a change. Thanks for your suggestion though. I seems like I'm not the only one having this problem.